# Helm upgrade not possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am running an AWS EKS k8s Cluster. On that I have several Helm charts deployed. Once I did the update to the latest k8s version I did not realize that one of this Deployments has a PodDisruptionBudget which has been removed in a k8s version.

Now I am not able to update the affected Helm Chart because PodDisruptionBudget is not known. I have removed it from Helm Charts, but that did not help.
I tried to uninstall the deployment but that was also not possible due to the same reason.

Now I have changed the Manifest inside the secret and removed the PodDisruptionBudget from there.

But when I do a `helm upgrade` now I get the error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress
```

`Helm history` give me:

```
37              Fri Nov 11 08:34:19 2022        failed                  dpn-1.1.0        1.1.0          
40              Sat Sep 16 19:54:04 2023        pending-rollback        dpn-1.1.0        4.17.1          Rollback to 39
```

I tried to remove the secrets 38 and 39 which where in pending uninstall state as well.
But that did not help, too.

Anything more I can try to be able to upgrade the helm chart? To re-setup the whole cluster would be lot of work...

Answer (score 0):

First of all `PodDisruptionBudget` is an object to define the max disruption that can be caused to a collection of pods.

As mentioned in the documentation, `PodDisruptionBudget` is not removed but, now it uses `policy/v1` instead of `policy/v1beta1`.

I would suggest delete the helm release `dpn-1.1.0` causing the issue and re-install it after that

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Deleting the release is not possible as well. It says me ````Error: failed to delete release: dpn-1.1.0````

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the previous helm deployment failed.

The easiest way to resolve is to rollback the helm release by running this cmd.

**Option 1**

```
helm rollback <release> --namespace <namespace>
```

if you want to list the release `helm ls --namespace <namespace>`

**Option 2**

Detele the last helm secret.

```
kubectl get secrets 
kubectl delete secret <last-helm-secret>
```